# Spring boot JPA findByUuid

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, uuid

I want to query the database for a given UUID that is not the primary key.I cannot make it works:

Here is my Node class. My PK is a long auto increment and I have a field called uuid for store the UUID key generated when a new node is saved in the database.

*Update: even if I get a node by id and then I use its node uuid to call the findByUuid function I am getting a null value*

```
    Node n = nodeService.getNodeByNodeId(1L);
    return nodeService.getNodeByNodeUuid(n.getApiKey());
```

**Node**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="node")
public class Node {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "node_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "node_seq", sequenceName = "node_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique=true)
private UUID uuid;


public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50, unique = true)
@NotNull    
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="node", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<User> users;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('MANAGER')")
    @RequestMapping(value="/node/{nodeUuidString}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Node getNodeByUuid(@PathVariable UUID nodeUuidString) {
       return nodeService.getNodeByNodeUuid(nodeUuidString);
}
```

I also get the nodeUuidString as a String and then converted to UUID with:

```
UUID nodeUuid = UUID.fromString(nodeUuidString);
```

But it did not worked.

**Service**

```
    public Node getNodeByNodeUuid(UUID nodeUuid) {
       return nodeRepository.findOneByUuid(nodeUuid);
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface NodeRepository extends CrudRepository<Node, Long> {

Node findOneByUuid(UUID nodeUuid);
```

}

Comment: show the Node class.  and also when you say it doesn't work what happens you getting any exception?

Comment: I don't think you need `findOneByUuid` try changing it to `findByUuid`

Comment: i have the same result with `findByUuid` and `findOneByUuid`

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any exception??

Comment: No, I am just getting a null value.

Comment: Try to rename the field 'uuid' to 'nodeId' (for example) - perhaps 'uuid' field is conflicting with 'uuid' type in SQL query. Also turn on 'show sql' parameter to check this...

Comment: I've changed the names and still not querying properly. If i get the node by id and then i use the method getUuid() as a parameter in the service method getbyuuid() i still getting a null value

Comment: uud is a Object of UUID class. How can it work. ? you are trying to search by object and not object property. Try using  `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")` annotation on uuid field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring was creating the field in the database as binary(255)

The correct one is binary(16)

So, for get the query working I had to use this annotation on the entity definition:

`@Column(name = "apiKey", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique=true, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")`

Answer (score 5):

The reason behind it is that by default hibernate translates `UUID` into `BINARY(255)` 255 being the default length value. 
The size of `UUID` is actually `BINARY(16)`. Thus causing in mismatch when they are compared.

The solution is to use specify the length for column as follows

```java
@Column(length=16)
UUID uuid;
```

**Note**: If you are using sql database that's not generated by the spring, you will have to alter the id column

```sql
alter table table_name modify column uuid binary(16);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write your own query if nothing works:

```
@Query("SELECT n FROM Node n WHERE n.uuid= ?1")
Node findOneByUuid(UUID nodeUuid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still giving me null.